# Find all links recursively using bs4 and Python problem

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm using the below code to recursively collect all links from the given website the only problem is that I get this in the beginning of the output file:

https://www.metatrader4.com/en/trading-platform/help/beginning/autotrading/en

https://www.metatrader4.com/en/trading-platform/help/beginning/autotrading/en/en

https://www.metatrader4.com/en/trading-platform/help/beginning/autotrading/en/en/en

...

https://www.metatrader4.com/en/trading-platform/help/beginning/autotrading/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en

etc..

How can I prevent/remove this?

The code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

# lists 
urls=[] 
   
# function created 
def scrape(site): 
       
    # getting the request from url 
    r = requests.get(site) 
       
    # converting the text 
    s = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"html.parser") 
       
    for i in s.find_all("a"):
          
        href = i.attrs['href'] 
           
        if href.startswith("/"): 
            site = site+href
               
            if site not in  urls: 
                urls.append(site)  
                print(site) 
                # calling it self 
                scrape(site) 
   
# main function 
if __name__ =="__main__": 
   
    # website to be scrape 
    site="https://www.metatrader4.com/en/trading-platform/help/beginning/autotrading"
   
    # calling function 
    scrape(site)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### What happens?

Your are replacing the site with itself + the `href` and first `href` it finds only contains `/en`.

### How to fix?

Instead of `site` use a `baseUrl`

```
baseUrl = "https://www.metatrader4.com/"
```

Not sure why you are calling `scrape()` over and over again I commented it out in my example, cause it is not necessary.

**Example**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

# lists 
urls=[] 
   
# function created 
def scrape(site, baseUrl): 
       
    # getting the request from url 
    r = requests.get(site) 
       
    # converting the text 
    s = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"html.parser") 
       
    for i in s.find_all("a"):
          
        href = i.attrs['href'] 
           
        if href.startswith("/"): 
            site = baseUrl+href
               
            if site not in  urls: 
                urls.append(site)  
                print(site) 
                # calling it self 
                # scrape(site, baseUrl) 
   
# main function 
if __name__ =="__main__": 
   
    # website to be scrape 
    site="https://www.metatrader4.com/en/trading-platform/help/beginning/autotrading"
    baseUrl = "https://www.metatrader4.com/"
    # calling function 
    scrape(site, baseUrl)
```

**Output**

> https://www.metatrader4.com/en
> https://www.metatrader4.com/en/trading-platform
> https://www.metatrader4.com/en/download
> https://www.metatrader4.com/en/trading-platform/forex
> https://www.metatrader4.com/en/trading-platform/orders
> https://www.metatrader4.com/en/trading-platform/technical-analysis
> https://www.metatrader4.com/en/trading-platform/alerts-news

Comment: I'm trying to collect all the links recursively in order to make a sitemap, that's why I'm calling scrape over and over. Or is there another way?